# GUI program can't allocate a console in Qt's debugger

Tags: qt, qt4, console, gdb

I have a GUI program that opens a Windows console in a separate window to display output and accept user input. My development environment is Qt 4.7.1 with mingw. The console works fine, until I try to run the program in Qt's debugger (gdb); then, although AllocConsole succeeds, and GetStdHandle appears to return a valid handle (0x000000d8), any attempt to use the handle causes Windows error 6 (invalid handle).

So I can't debug my program. Which is a pain, because it has some serious bugs. The problem may be that gdb's console prevents me opening my own console; but then why do AllocConsole and GetStdHandle succeed? I upgraded to Qt Creator 2.0.94 (Qt 4.7.1), but it didn't help. Any ideas?

**Update** I have found that I can debug the program by running it without the debugger, and then attaching to it from Qt. Not ideal, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the standard output console, using 
CONFIG += console 
in the .pro file?

Hmm -- check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) out:

> A process can be associated with only one console, so the AllocConsole function fails if the calling process already has a console. A process can use the FreeConsole function to detach itself from its current console, then it can call AllocConsole to create a new console or AttachConsole to attach to another console.

Can you try running FreeConsole before you create yours?