# exe with console and gui mode

Tags: qt

I compile my qt-project with += console option,
I need it to debug version, and for release I rebuild
project with -= console

But sometimes I need enable\show console output in release version of my app.

So my question is - Is it possible to pass some argument (line -show_console) to
my .exe to start app with console or without (if no option specified)?

Answer (score 1):

I have an application with a GUI window and a console window. I open the console window using [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the Windows API. The trouble is, Qt can't debug it, at least using gdb, because gdb needs a console too. But see [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868411/gui-program-cant-allocate-a-console-in-qts-debugger) for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want a gui app that also writes to the console then under windows you need to [reopen the console](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q105305/).

Alternatively - Set the application type to console ( ie /subsystem:console in windows) but still write the normal Qt gui code, it will open a console and you can use std::cout

Comment: but my app is GUI - i mean GUI part must be shown always, but console by option

Comment: In windows you need to set the system type so it calls the correct main, in MSVC properties->linker->system>subsytem